# How do I let a computed observable be set via entering or from being calculated from other inputs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.deckareax = ko.observable(0);
        self.deckareay = ko.observable(0);
        self.calculatedarea = ko.observable(20);
        self.deckareax.subscribe(function () {
            if (self.deckareax() == 0 || deckareay == 0) {
                self.calculatedarea(0);
            } else {
                self.calculatedarea(self.deckareax() * self.deckareay());
            }
        }
        );
        self.deckareay.subscribe(function () {
            console.log("deckareay " + self.deckareay())

            if (self.deckareax() == 0 || self.deckareay() == 0) {
                self.calculatedarea(0);
            } else {
                self.calculatedarea(self.deckareax() * self.deckareay());
            }

        }
        );
        self.deckareamxm = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                return self.calculatedarea();
            },
            write: function (value) {
                self.calculatedarea(value);
                if ((self.deckareax() * self.deckareay(0)) != value) {
                    self.deckareax(0);
                    self.deckareay(0);
                }

            },
                owner:self
        });
    }

    ;

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I want to be able to set the total area (deckareamxm) by either manually inputting or calcualting from entering deckareax * deckareay. If I enter a result and (deckareax * deckareay) doesn't equal total deck area x and y should be cleared.

This pretty much works however if I enter total area it clears both but also clears itself. If I then enter again total area it stays. I think it may have got to complex. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `0` in this line just a typo: `(self.deckareax() * self.deckareay(0) != value)` ?

Comment: Yeah. Well error in my actual code as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erANj/) seems to do what you want. There were a couple other bugs but I primary fixed the problem by moving the `self.calculatedarea(value);` to the bottom of the write function.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't spot them. I think my mind goes a bit blank with Knockoutjs. Am I making this overly complex BTW? Is there a cleaner easier way to achieve this?